# How we can show last data point of log-log plot of complementary cdf in python?

Tags: python, statistics, cdf, loglog

I have a question about log-log plot of complementary cdf in python.
I know the process but the main problem is last data point.
As you know complementary cdf is 1-cdf, so this means last data point is zero.
Therefore, when you want to plot it in log log scale, python remove the last data point but I want to have it in a standard way.

I expect to get last data point in my plot but it removes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.